# Programmatically supress Outlook email send warning message using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Currently, I have a group of coding that is set to auto-send an email generated on prior user input.

When this is called, it privately generates/sends an email - but asks the user accept "Okay", "Cancel", or "Help".

If the user exits the pane or clicks Cancel, the email is not sent.

Is there a way to have the program auto-select the command Okay?

```
Private Sub sendemail()

Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim mitem As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim email_ As String
Dim subject_ As String
Dim body_ As String
Dim attach_ As String

'''>>>EMAIL<<<'''
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


email_ = "SomeEmail@Email.com"
subject_ = "General Subject"
body_ = "General Message"

 'create Mail Item and send it
Set mitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)
With mitem
    .To = email_
    .Subject = subject_
    .Body = body_
     '.Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt"
     '.Display 'To Display the message with an option to send or cancel

    .Send 'To auto-send the message
End With

End Sub
```

I've tried using the following code, but think I may be using it in the wrong places as it has been unsuccessful:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'With function/code

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: In the Outlook options under Security Tab, you will find a checkbox next to "Warn me when other applications try to send mail as me". Just uncheck this checkbox.

Comment: Where there will be approximately 100 individuals using this system, is this something every user would need to do? Or is there anything I could add to the code for it to just automatically select the "Okay" option?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Set mitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)
With mitem
    .To = email_
    .Subject = subject_
    .Body = body_
     '.Attachments.Add "C:\FolderName\Filename.txt"
     .Display 'To Display the message with an option to send or cancel
     Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
     Application.SendKeys "%s"
End With
```